# Date difference: different results in Excel vs. Python

Tags: python, excel, date, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe with two dates columns with timestamp ( i want to keep time stamp)
I want to get the difference in days between those two dates , I used the below . It works just fine.

```
mergethetwo['diff_days']=(mergethetwo['todaydate']-mergethetwo['LastLogon']).dt.days
```

The doubt is , when I got the difference between those two dates in Excel , it gave me different number.

In python for example the difference between

> > 5/15/2020  1:48:00 PM (LastLogon)   **and**   6/21/2020  12:00:00 AM(todaydate)  is 36 .

However , in Excel using

> > DATEDIF =(LastLogon,todaydate,"d")
> > 5/15/2020  1:48:00 PM  **and** 6/21/2020  12:00:00 AM is 37 days !

Why is the difference ? Which one should I trust ? As I have 30,000 + rows I can't go through all od them to confirm.

Appreciate your support
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel `DATEDIF` with `"D"` seems to count "started" days (*dates*, as the name of the function says...); whilst the Python timedelta gives the actual delta in time - 36.425 days:

```
import pandas as pd

td = pd.to_datetime("6/21/2020 12:00:00 AM")-pd.to_datetime("5/15/2020 1:48:00 PM")
# Timedelta('36 days 10:12:00')

td.days
# 36

td.total_seconds() / 86400
# 36.425
```

You will get the same result if you do `todaydate-LastLogon` in Excel, without using any function.

Comment: I could not find any reference that `DATEDIF` is supposed to be used with times, only with dates. So I guess the time is ignored.

Comment: @Joe: that's a good point! One could guess it from the name of the function... Couldn't find anything specific in [the docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c) that it's "rounding up" to full days or ignoring time though.

Comment: I noticed that Python datatime above , exclude both dates . While excel datedif function include one of the dates that is why its always 1 additional day than python datatime

Comment: @Eithar: I think in both Excel and Python, it is not totally obvious what is going on at first sight. However I'd prefer the Python [timdelta docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) when it's about *understanding* what's going on and how to use it.